# multiple tree views for same model odoo version 8

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

i have a problem !
well I've been trying to inherit the model product.template and create a new menu-item and action window in order to call a new independent tree view
but my new tree view is affecting the old one ! here's my code !

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
 <data>
  <record id="new_view_tree_modif_product" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">new_view_tree_modif_product</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <tree editable="bottom" create="0" colors="red:inf_marge_min==True">
          <field name="name" string="Nom" readonly="1"/>
          <field name="standard_price" string="Prix de revient" readonly="1"/>
          <field name="marge" string="Marge"/>
          <field name="list_price" string="Prix de vente"/>
          <field name="inf_marge_min" invisible="1"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
  </record>
  <act_window id="action_new_view_product"
              name="Etude de prix"
              res_model="product.template"
              view_mode="tree" />
  <menuitem id="menu_prix_modif_product"
            name="Prix"
            parent="base.menu_product"
            sequence="9"
            action="action_new_view_product" />
  <record id="tree_id" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field eval="3" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="new_view_tree_modif_product"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_new_view_product"/>
  </record>
</data>
```

well its affecting the default tree view
how can i call my tree view without affecting old one 
thnx

Comment: Seems weird. How do you know it is affecting the default tree view, how can it be seen in the client? The xml looks fine or it's too late and i'm blind ;-)

Comment: well , when i went check the other tree view ( template view ) its the same as mine if i add a new field to my view its gonna be the same on the original :/

Comment: Add field `priority` to your `ir.ui.view` record with value 100. Then try it out again.

Comment: Add the view_id to your act_window

`<act_window id="action_new_view_product"
              name="Etude de prix"
              res_model="product.template"
              view_id = "new_view_tree_modif_product"
              view_mode="tree" />`

Comment: hi guys thnx for answers , well i just post my solution , its pretty easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well in order to achieve this , i had to  create a main action wich regroup two actions for the new views :

```
<record id="action_1" model="ir.actions.act_window">
   <field name="name">new view</field>                                         
   <field name="res_model">model.name</field>                                  
   <field name="view_type">form</field>                                        
   <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>                                   
   <field eval="False" name="view_id"/>                                        
</record>
```

so this is the main action , now we should create actions for each view:
action 1 for our new tree view

```
<record id="action_new_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">     
    <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>  
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>  
    <field name="view_id" ref="external id of your new tree view"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_1"/>
</record>
```

now we made an action for our new tree view , and link it the first action ,we should do the same for the form

```
<record id="action_new_form" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">     
    <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>  
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>  
    <field name="view_id" ref="external id of your new form view"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_1"/>
</record>
```

perfect , all we need now is to create a menuitem for the first action (action1)

```
<menuitem id="id_of_ur_new_menu"  
 name="new form and tree view for an existing model"               
 parent="parent.menu "               
 action="action_1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the view type and priority.

```
<field name="type">tree</field>
<field name="priority" eval="20"/>
```

The default priority of a view is 16. Lower values mean higher priority, and vice-verse. Just set your view with lower priority than the original one, and Odoo will not prefer it unless you specify it explicitly.

A brief info on views priority: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html

Comment: it was the only solution that worked with me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Add this line ' primary ' to your code, then it will not affect the default tree view.

```
<record id="tree_id" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field eval="3" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="new_view_tree_modif_product"/>
    <field name="mode">primary</field>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_new_view_product"/>
```